# How can i extend the rich text editor behavior?

Tags: visual-studio, application-pages, rich-text, image-upload, rte

I want to extend the behavior of *RteUploadDialog.aspx*. When inserting a image in Rich Text Editor, i would like to upload the image to another server Image Library. I guess i could create an Application Page, am i correct?

I saw similar problem in this question: [Created a custom image uploader for the Rich Text Editor, but how do I insert the image?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44017/created-a-custom-image-uploader-for-the-rich-text-editor-but-how-do-i-insert-th) from [Abe Miessler](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1941/abe-miessler).

What I need is exactly that, but i don't know where to start.

Please, someone could help me?